# Material-UI: Restrict specific special characters in TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I put a validation or not allow to enter the following special characters `[^%<>\\$'"]` on the Material-UI `TextField`.

Below are my existing codes.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
textField: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 500,
},
FormLabelHeader:{
    fontSize: '20px',
    width: 500,
},
})
enter code here
const txtNameChange = (e) =>
{
    setpersonDetails(prevState =>({
        ...prevState,
        'NAME' : e.target.value
    }))
}

.....
<FormControl>
   <FormLabel className = {style.FormLabelHeader}>Add</FormLabel><br/>
   <TextField className = {style.textField} label='NAME' name = 'NAME' variant='outlined' autoComplete='off' onChange={txtNameChange}/><br />
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I put a validation

You can provide an error message after validating the value by setting the `helperText` and `error` props of `TextField`:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const onChange = (e) => {
  const newValue = e.target.value;

  if (!newValue.match(/[%<>\\$'"]/)) {
    setError("");
  } else {
    setError("Forbidden character: %<>$'\"");
  }
  setName(newValue);
};

return (
  <TextField
    value={name}
    onChange={onChange}
    helperText={error} // error message
    error={!!error} // set to true to change the border/helperText color to red
  />
);
```

> or not allow to enter

Since you've already controlled the value of `TextField` in your code, simply don't update the state if the validation failed:

```js
const onChange = (e) => {
  const newValue = e.target.value;

  if (!newValue.match(/[%<>\\$'"]/)) {
    setError("");
    setName(newValue); // only set when successful
  } else {
    setError("Forbidden character: %<>$'\"");
  }
};
```

[image: Edit 66848152/material-ui-restrict-specific-special-characters-in-textfield]

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, i tried and followed what you've said but even I put invalid characters, It always go to `if` and not redirected to `else` . Invalid special characters saved to `setName`. Hope you can help me with this. Thank you

Comment: @Rymrk Sorry, my bad. Fixed in the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, thank you, it is now working. how about if I want to add other special characters, where should I put it? for example `[ ]`. I tried to put it but only `[` is being validated. Thank you

Comment: `[` and `]` are special characters in regex. Try escaping it: `\[` and `\]` @Rymrk

Comment: thank you! Apologies I did not included this in  the question. How about if I want to put Min and Max characters?

Comment: You can check the length of the string value and see if it satisfies the constraint: `if (newValue.length > 0 || newValue.length < n)` for example @Rymrk

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, in relation to this issue. I encountered new issue when it comes to edit. Should I edit this post or post another question? Can you help me again? Thank you

Comment: You should avoid asking multiple questions in a single post because it may get closed due to the lack of focusing. Please open a new question. I'll have a look at it when I have time. @Rymrk

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, noted on this. I posted new question here's the link [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866051/material-ui-unable-to-delete-data-in-textfield-during-update-with-character-and

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866051/material-ui-unable-to-delete-data-in-textfield-during-update-with-character-and