# Material-UI: Unable to delete data in TextField during Update with character and length restrictions reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848152/material-ui-restrict-specific-special-characters-in-textfield) question, I can't delete the data inside of TextField during update due to restrictions I made on `onChange` during `insert`.

See below codes.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState({
   Name: '',
   ....
});
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const onChange = (e) => {
  const newValue = e.target.value;
if(newValue .length > 7 && newValue .length <= 50){
  if (!newValue.match(/[%<>\\$'"]/)) {
      setError("");
      setDetails(prevState=>({
       ...prevState, 'Name' : e.target.value
      }));
  } else {
      setError("Unforbidden character: %<>$'\"");
  }
else {
      setError("Invalid length");
}
}
};

return (
  <TextField
    value={name}
    onChange={onChange}
    value={details&&details.Name}
    helperText={error} // error message
    error={!!error} // set to true to change the border/helperText color to red
  />
);
```

Below was the output upon edit. (deleting the value of TextField, it stucked on the required min length, and upon inputing invalid characters, it displays the error but not the invalid characters.) Unlike the behavior during insert.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should check for all invalid cases first using `if` and `else if`, only in the last case where all of the checks are passed, you can finally call `setError("")` to  indicate there are no error. See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/66848152material-ui-restrict-specific-special-characters-in-textfield-forked-wx8e5?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, noted on this. Than you

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, I followed your statements on your demo, however I still encountering same error. By default `Name` has a value of `1234567890` when I erase the value and meet the condition `< 7` it stuck and can't erase other values on `TextField`.

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl, I see.. I'm encountering the error because I put the setName inside `else`. However, even I encountered an error, the `newValue` will be saved to `setName`  thats why I put it inside else to make sure no encountered error upon `setName`.